# 2D transformation matrix order?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, transformation

Rotate a triangle with vertices (2, 1). (4. 1). (3, 3) by 90 degrees (clock wise) and then Translate it by Tx 4 and Ty 3 and finally rotate it by 30 degrees (anti-clock wise). (cos90=0, sin90 1. cos 30 = 0.866, sin30 =0.5)

T1 is Rotation with 90 T2 is Translation T3 is Rotation with 30

What is correct order of transformation matrix to multiply the metrix?

T3 T2 T1 or T1 T2 T3?

Should i follow the order given by the question or reverse order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T3@T2@T1@vertices since the T1 matrix will be applied first. Here is the representation with parentheses to emphasize the order of operations:

T3@(T2@(T1@vertices))

P.S. the @ symbol is how you multiply matrices in python.

Comment: Thanks @zachistician

Answer (score 2):

The order depends on whether you’re working with *column* vectors and left-multiply by a matrix to transform them (the common mathematical convention), or with *row* vectors that get right-multiplied by transformation matrices.

A simple way to remember the correct order of multiplication is that when you compose transformations, each successive transformation is applied to the result of the previous one—the chain of multiplications grows away from the thing being transformed. Thus, using the *column* vector convention, if you want to transform a vector $\mathbf v$ first by $T_1$ and then by $T_2$, you would first compute $T_1\mathbf v$ and then $T_2(T_1)\mathbf v = (T_2T_1)\mathbf v$. With three transformations, it would be $T_3(T_2(T_1\mathbf v)) = (T_3T_2T_1)\mathbf v$. If we’re instead working with row vectors, the chain of multiplications would grow to the right instead of the left as above.

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot that there are two different and equally valid notations for vectors. The other way always confused the crap out of me so I just neglect it, sort of like trying to think of current in terms of flow of negative charge instead of positive charge.